# Ember.js data is not getting loaded in ObjectController

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently working on a pure client side app that ueses LocalStorage to persist data. I need to save some settings data and am runinng in into some truble with the data loading. The data is persisted corretly, but is note retrived properly. I guess I'm getting somting worng with the Embers's [ObjectController](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/representing-a-single-model-with-objectcontroller).

JS Bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pelol/1/edit

Why isn't the data being loaded into the placeholder of the input elements? Or should I do something completely different for data like a single settings set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `App.settingsRoute` to:

```
App.SettingsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('settings', '1');
  }
});
```

You should also change your `{{input}}`s to:

```
<p>Name</p>
{{input type="text" placeholder="name" valueBiding="name" }} 
<p>Home base</p>
{{input type="text" placeholder="homeBase" valueBinding="homeBase" }}
```

See [this jsBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pelol/3/).

Comment: Thanks! This was driving me crazy! But for some reason the saving returns the following error: `Assertion failed: Cannot delegate set('userName', Dave) to the 'content' property of object proxy <DS.PromiseObject:ember396>: its 'content' is undefined.`. Same code, but the controller name was wrong in the original JS Bin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pelol/9/edit

Comment: That's because `find()` returns a [promise](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/), not the settings object. See http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pelol/10/

Comment: Still really need to spend some more time with the concept of ember. Thanks for your help and setting me on the right path!

Comment: No problem. Best of luck = there is a bit of a learning curve in the beginning, but it is well worth it